# Continuity on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Question:

Let $f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb R$ be continuous on $(0, 1)$ with $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = 0 $ and $\lim_{x\to 1−} f(x) = 1$.

Prove that if $\lambda \in (0, 1) $ then there exists $ c \in (0, 1) $ such that $f(c) = \lambda $.

I understand why the limits being $0$ and $1$ allow there to be  a $c$ s.t $f(c) = \lambda$, but not sure how to structure my answer, can I somehow adapt the IVT?

Comment: *Hint:* Define a continuous function $g$ on the closed interval $[0, 1|$ which coincides with $f$ on $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Show that there exist $a,b \in (0,1)$ such that $a<b$ and $f(a) <\lambda < f(b)$. Apply MVT to $[a,b]$.

Comment: Edited using latex for mathematics.  Please check and let me know if I've made any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x)= \begin {cases} \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x) ; x=0\\ f(x); x\in (0,1)\\ \lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x); x=1 \end{cases}$

Note that $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Now define $p(x) = g(x) -\lambda$. We have $p(0)=-\lambda$ and $p(1)=1-\lambda\gt 0$ and hence by IVT there is a $c\in (0,1)$ such that $p(c)=0$ and hence $g(c)=\lambda$ , which is $f(c)$ by definition of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the image of $(0,1)$ by the function $f$ : by IVT, $I$ is an interval. Now, because $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1-} f(x) = 1$, then $I$ must contain $0$ and $1$ in its closure, so $I$ must contain the interval $(0,1)$. In particular, $I$ contains $\lambda$ and you are done.